# Clone a form input as a jQuery Object And Display it with wrap div / li

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm am getting [object Object] or [object HTMLInputElement] when I try to wrap or add more html content to the jQuery selectors.

I'm trying to:

1. Copy a input field
2. Clear out any data (keep id, class, type
   ect...)  (issue with firefox was retaining the data, why I manually
   cleared out the data )
3. Wrap input with a list tag and include
   a button (div element)

I was able to make this work part way, I was able to do the combination of any two of the three things above (weird right?).  The main problem, when using the code I have for all three steps, I keep getting `[object Object]` or `[object HTMLInputElement]`. (I was able to append item and that fixed the object object problem, but then I wasn't able to wrap it and add button).

Here my html code:

```
<section id="fileInputs">
    <li>
        <!-- Jquery looks for li to add more of these -->
        <input multiple name="filetoupload001" type="file">
        <div class="square clicked">
            <span class="plus"><i class="fa fa-plus plus"></i></span>
            <span class="minus"><i class="fa fa-minus minus"></i></span>
        </div>
    </li>
</section>
```

Here my jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $("#fileInputs").on("change", "input[type=file]", function() {
            var item = $(this).clone(false);
            //var item = $.extend({}, $(this) ); //Seems same results as clone

            item[0].name = "filetoupload002" //I have a function -> leftPad(i, 3);
            item[0].files[0] = ''; //Firefox fix/hack - Clear out those pesky file that shouldn't have copy over since .clone() not supoose to copy data
            item[0].value = '';

            var a = document.createElement('li');
            var b = item; // Shows [object Object]
            // var b = item[0]; // Shows [object HTMLInputElement]
            // var b = $.parseHTML(item); // null
            // var b = $.parseHTML(item[0]); // null
            // var b = '<input multiple name="filetoupload'+leftPad(i, 3)+'" type="file"></input> '; // Work Perfect!! However would like to use item insted
            var c = '<div class="square"><span class="plus"><i class="fa fa-plus plus"></i></span><span class="minus"><i class="fa fa-minus minus"></i></span></div></li>';

            a.innerHTML = b;
            a.innerHTML += c;

            $(this).parent().parent().append(a); // This is the end result I want however would like to use clone item instead of hard code html
        }
    });
});
```

I been going at this for hours, really could use some help here. In the mean time, I will be starting over and try to:

1. Copy list that contains one input and one div(button)
2. Clear out input data
3. Output new input onscreen within section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were getting [object HTMLInputElement] for **b** because you were trying to add object created by JavaScript to innerHTML instead of the element's HTML string. You can use outerHTML for that.

Also, notice here that you need to get raw DOM element from item, hence you need to use b = item[0].

```
$(function() {
  $("#fileInputs").on("change", "input[type=file]", function () {
    var item = $(this).clone(true, true);

    item[0].name = "filetoupload002"//I have a function -> leftPad(i, 3);
    item[0].files[0] = ''; //Firefox fix/hack - Clear out those pesky file that shouldn't have copy over since .clone() not supoose to copy data
    item[0].value = '';

    var a = document.createElement('li'); // Element created using JavaScript    
    var b = item[0];            
    var c = '<div class="square"><span class="plus"><i class="fa fa-plus plus"></i></span><span class="minus"><i class="fa fa-minus minus"></i></span></div></li>';

    a.innerHTML += b.outerHTML;
    a.innerHTML += c;

    $(this).parent().parent().append(a);        
  });
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cgv8runb/

Answer (score 1):

A much simpler pattern to follow is to keep the name of all the file inputs the same and access them by index on the server. This also saves the headache of having to maintain the incremental names when new items are added or removed. Then you can just copy the parent `li` of the changed input. Try this:

```
$("#fileInputs").on("change", "input[type=file]", function(){
    var $li = $(this).closest('li').clone();
    $li.find('input').prop({
        files: [],
        value: ''
    });
    $('#fileInputs').append($li);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/h66e4om4/)